# Is it possible to determine the maximum size of physical memory from a Page Table Entry?

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, virtual-memory

Say a computer has a 16bit virtual address space. The maximum addressable virtual memory is 2^16 = around 64kb.

Suppose page size is 8kb or 2^13 bits, there are 8 pages (2^(16-3)), and a Page Table Entry has a 9 bit frame number.

Is it possible to determine the maximum size of physical memory from this?

I'm trying to understand the translation from virtual to phyiscal address better. I think the answer could be 2^9 * 2 ^13 but that would leave a lot of gaps in the actual physical address. I want to understand if this is usually acceptable

Thanks

Comment: Assuming there's no "unexpected shenanigans" (e.g. some kind of bank switching scheme); the max. physical address space size would be 2^9 * 2 ^13 (4 MiB), and the max. physical memory would be "max. physical address space size - min. space consumed by things that aren't memory". Why do you think that would leave a lot of gaps in the physical addresses?

Comment: Hi brendan, thanks for commenting. Because the virtual address space is only 16 bits, so there are 3 bits for the page index i.e. 8 pages only, but 2^9 possible frame addresses. But then again I guess it makes sense since the whole point was to translate it from virtual to logical space. If that makes sense to you as well if you want to put that as an answer I can vote it correct?

Comment: Don't forget that there can be (and typically is) many virtual address spaces but only one physical address space. E.g. with 100 processes running and 64 KiB for each individual virtual address space, it'd add up to a total of 6400 KiB of virtual address spaces (and would be larger than physical memory; which is fine because a lot of virtual space is unused or used for data on disk, or is memory that's shared by multiple processes).